# python watchdog monitor directory changes on remote machine

Tags: python, linux, file, monitor, watchdog

I'm using watchdog to monitor some logs changes on local windows directory.
Now I need also to monitor logs on remote linux machine.

Any idea how can I do it using watchdog ?

Thanks !
Uri

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the linux-machine's directory you are interested in as a share. Then Windows should generate FS-notifications watchdog can observe.

For restrictions, see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx